# Alignment issue in the stackexchange.com search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, stackexchange.com

There is an alignment issue in the stackexchange.com search page .

The bottom bar is missing in the search input box.

Sample URL: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=AngularJS+ng-bind+with+a+function

Screen shot for reference:

[image: SE Search bar]

Firefox version: 54.0b8 (32-bit)
OS Version: Windows 10 Pro

Also happens with Chrome latest version.

Comment: In addition to this, the font looks a bit different in Firefox than it does in Chrome. Adding `font-family: inherit` helps. http://i.imgur.com/fJ0LeK4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment issue in the search bar has been fixed in the recent design change.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: StackExchange.com]