# Wrong font for Google custom search

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, search-engine

Seems there is wrong font size in the [Stack Exchange Google custom search page](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=stackoverflow):

> [image: fontoverflow]

Bottom border of the search box is obscured.

Comment: Dupe for bottom border issue: [Alignment issue in the stackexchange.com search page - Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296153/312043)

Comment: Confirmed, Windows 7, Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Using Windows7(enterprise)  62.0.3202.94(Offical Build) (64-bit)